# Some error in file downloading after uploading file to S3 using laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have uploaded file to s3. after changing its name and adding a timestamp to name

The same code is working fine on local Linux server. but having issue on aws linux server

Code I have used to download file using streams

```
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$fileName);
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Connection: Keep-Alive');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . $size);

    if (!($stream = fopen($response, 'r'))) {
        throw new \Exception('Could not open stream for reading file: ['.$fileName.']');
    }
    // Check if the stream has more data to read
    while (!feof($stream)) {
        // Read 1024 bytes from the stream
        echo fread($stream, 1024);
    }
    // Be sure to close the stream resource when you're done with it
    fclose($stream);
```

If I have uploaded a jpg image. Then after downloading the same file gives an error.

Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x0a 0xff)